# Why am I getting: Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a total newbie to Rails, and I am following the Railsbridge Intro to Rails.  I have created my project and now I am trying to create a new controller action for voting, and a new route for voting.  When I go to the development page, it shows the following message:

> Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake
>   db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

In the command line it gives me this information:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
undefined method `migrate' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefiniti
on:0x5d79e78>C:/Sites/railsbridgejan/suggestotron/db/migrate/20150129195744_create_votes.rb:6:in `block in change' C:/Sites/railsbridgejan/suggestotron/db/migrate/20150129195744_create_votes.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So, when I look in my db files for create_votes.rb this is what it looks like:

```
  class CreateVotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table :votes do |t|
         t.integer :topic_id
         t.string :rake
         t.migrate :db

         t.timestamps null: false
       end
     end
   end
```

Is there something wrong with my file's code?  t.migrate :db    is line 6, which according to the command line, is the problem.  I am using Rails 4, Ruby 2, and Sqlite.  I had tried to install MySql, but I ran into some major issues, so I just continued with Sqlite.  Could that be causing this problem at all?  It seems like the issue is in the code listed above, but I'm not sure.
Thank you!

Comment: `migrate` is not a method available on that object. What are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `change` method you use

```
t.migrate :db
```

The `migrate` data type doesn't exist. I assume you wanted to use a String.

```
t.string :db
```